# jQuery quantity (input val) + / - buttons not working on IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-7

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/9Vvpj/4/

Please help me figure out why this working fine in EVERYTHING other than IE7!

It looks like my variable:

```
var quantity = quantity_input.val();
```

is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the same ID for different elements.  Even in browsers that support it, it's not how the DOM is supposed to work.

If you use this code to find your input you won't even need the IDs:

```
var quantity_input = $(this).parent().siblings(".quantity")
```

It's also a good idea to explicitly specify that you're working with a number:

```
var quantity = parseInt(quantity_input.val());
```

Note that this method works when using developer tools to switch to IE7:
http://jsfiddle.net/9Vvpj/5/

Comment: It is undefined in IE7, everywhere else it's fine.

Comment: Try the fiddle I saved in IE7.

Comment: @Dave your last jsfiddle isnt valid HTML - you still have duplicate IDs

Comment: True.  But you'll notice my answer says not to do that, and I didn't post any code in my answer that has or depends on them.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have multiple IDs on a single document - that is why your code isn't working ....

Try this instead :

```
    var this_id = jQuery(this).data('input');
```

this uses the [`data()` function](http://api.jquery.com/data/)  to get the 'data-input` property within the HTML. I updated the HTML too, instead of

```
<div id="CartProduct-118" class="quantityDown">-</div>
```

do

```
<div data-input="CartProduct-118" class="quantityDown">-</div>
```

[Working exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/9Vvpj/3/)

Comment: Thanks, could you suggest another way of doing this then?

Comment: Also, when I debug the variable "quantity_input", it is an object... so I don't see why I can't get the value of it.

Comment: @RegionalC it might well be an object - but check its length

Comment: To clarify, jQuery always returns an object.  Doesn't mean it's the one you want, or that there's anything in it.

Comment: @RegionalC whats the error now ? which line ? does the example i posted work ?

Comment: Sorry.  I had fixed it by adding parseInt, without realizing the deeper issues in locating the proper input field.

Comment: Seems like...

HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=EmulateIE7') ignored because document mode is already finalized. 


And that's just a warning - I don't have other errors on the page and it still doesn't work in IE7.

Comment: @RegionalC dont have IE7 - only IE9 / Chrome and Firefox ... works fine for me - you might need to add the `parseInt()` as suggested by Dave too

Comment: In IE9 you can hit F12 to open dev tools and switch to IE7 mode. Doesn't work in there.

Comment: @RegionalC I would suggest thats a problem with the jsfiddle and the Developer tools - try it on a native IE7 client

Comment: I updated the code to include your answer and Dave's [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9Vvpj/4/) still no luck.

Comment: @RegionalC thats still not valid HTML - its got duplicate IDs ... try this : http://jsfiddle.net/9Vvpj/6/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to switch to this component:
http://view.jqueryui.com/master/demos/spinner/default.html

To make it work in webkit browsers you have to add this to css:

```
                input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
                input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button
                {
                    -webkit-appearance: none;
                    margin: 0;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks but that is really overkill for what I need. My code is only a few lines.